# Inserting a video into MediaStore

Tags: android, video, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I'm trying to insert a video into the `MediaStore`, the same way it's possible to store an image using this method:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), imagePath, null, null)
```

Since there's no similar method on `MediaStore.Video.Media`, what I tried to do was insert a record into `MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` and then copy the file to the destination, as shown below:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "Title1");
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, videoPath);
Uri uri = cr.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

try {
    OutputStream os = cr.openOutputStream(uri);
    ...
    ...
} (FileNotFoundException e) {
    cr.delete(uri, null, null);
}
```

The `uri` returned is `non-null` in the form of `content://media/external/video/media/{id}`, which seems correct.

But then when `cr.openOutputStream(uri);` is exectued, a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown.

This last bit is similar to what is done for [Images.Media.insertImage](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b4569fb17fada4fdc43e4f4dbfbc79bb097a1f74/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java#785) looking at its source code.

Btw, I do have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Also, I'm testing on 4.3 & 4.4.

Comment: I have this same problem on my Nexus 5 with 4.4.4.

Comment: any solutions people?

Comment: did you find any solutions?

Comment: Anyone resolved this?

Comment: Sadly, I never have been able to save a video in gallery using MediaStore. The only solution I found was to do a classic file saving through streams, and then use the MediaScanner intent to scan the output file, so it's added to the phone's gallery. If you're not trying to absolutely use MediaStore, I can post my solution (using Xamarin/C# but the code is almost identical, it's just the syntax and the indentation that changes), but if you really want to use MediaStore, it won't answer your question..

Answer (score 9):

What you get from this piece of code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "Title1");
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, videoPath);
Uri uri = cr.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

is a public `Uri`. More about is can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html), where you can see, that since API 19 (KitKat) the access to `Media` has changed.

By looking into source code of Android you could see a [database video schema and columns](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java#1875). [`VideoColumns`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java#1875) extend from [`MediaColumns`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java#322), which has the column:

```
MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA
```

described as:

> [Path to the file on disk.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#DATA)

So you must get the real `Uri` from public `Uri`.

In order to to this run the code:

```
getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
```

where `uri` is your public `Uri` and the function `getDataColumn` look like:

```
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA;
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This code comes from [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser) and the function [`getPath`](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java#L257)

Comment: uri returns null